# MAAS - Possible to apply certain cloud init or curtin scripts to only machines with certain tags?

Tags: maas

I want to learn how to automatically provision certain boxes with specific curtin or cloud init scripts and control which machine gets what with tags. Is this common usage of MAAS and supported?

Note I am not in an Enterprise environment and have set up MAAS on a used PowerEdge that I use for experimentation and learning.

For instance I might have the following tags with the following characteristics

- Desktop: Has a desktop and remote desktop access enabled
- Docker: set up to have Docker and run containers
- ...

Thanks